# firing one animation after another with delay

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, animation

I have two objects that fade into display simultaneously that are initially set to `hidden`, I want to fire the second animation a couple of seconds after the first but they both fade in at the same time?

```
_text.alpha = 0;

_text.hidden = NO;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.9 animations:^{
   _text.alpha = 1;


}];

////////////second animation

_note.alpha = 0;

_note.hidden = NO;

[UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.9 animations:^{
    _note.alpha = 1;


}];
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "make sure ..." :D .... see this `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` - [see the specifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW110)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.9 animations:^{
    _text.alpha = 1;    
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.9 animations:^{
       _note.alpha = 1;
    }];

}];
```

The second block gets called when the first animation ended.

Comment: Ahh thats it, that helped me understand the animation block principals.  Thanks very much for that

Answer (score 2):

Use the `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` method as described in the [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a). Put the second animation into the completion block of the first one.